# Can you get an extra attack after casting a spell whilst hasted?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

My Fighter 4/Sorcerer 6 has the ability to cast *haste* on himself, which says that he

> gains an additional action

but it can only be used to take the attack action (one weapon attack only).

Would he be able to cast a spell and than make a melee attack as well on the same turn whilst he is hasted?

Comment: Not just an Attack action, though. The rule for *Haste* says: *That action can be used only to take the Attack (one weapon attack only), Dash, Disengage, Hide, or Use an Object action.*

Answer (score 8):

Yes, that is exactly what it means - you use your normal action to take the Cast a Spell action and the action *Haste* gives you to take the Attack Action but you can only make one attack with that action.

Comment: Hahs thanks for the clear up, thought it just acted like extra attack so they needed to do make a weapon attack for it too trigger.